# Newbie in ML - how to

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

We have a data set of n variables (profile attributes) and want to feed through a model, and classify into M buckets (functionally signifying some action to be performed) .  Which MLmodel/ algorithm is best suited for this. Can someone point me some code.

Comment: Google Search for ML books and AndrewNG Course

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing an example code in python:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = whatever your data (X are the input variables, y are the output)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

lr = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

print("Training set accuracy: {:.2f}".format(lr.score(X_train, y_train))
print("Test set accuracy: {:.2f}".format(lr.score(X_test, y_test))
```

1. Imported necessary packages.
2. Defined your input (X) and output data (y).
3. Shuffled the data into the training set (75%) and the test set (25%).
4. Defined the linear regression model and fitted the training data.
5. Printed training and test set accuracies.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a broad question so it is difficult to answer correctly. The correct model really depends on a multitude of things. Given the fact that you seem to have n-features per data point and M possible outcomes, perhaps you should try a multivariate regression model first?

Comment: How and where can i find some sample code for this.